# how to set application locale?

Tags: android

i have an android application in which i need to set the whole application locale to german. i don't want to go into each and every acitivity....when the splashactivity/ welcome screen comes, i want the locale to be set for all the activities in my application. how do i go about this?

to summarize my question: how to set the locale of the android application(not an activity).
thank you in advance.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically

Comment: no , this does not help. i need to set the locale of the whole application. here what they are suggesting is that i write the code snippet they have given in the onResume method of all activities.

Comment: Actually the code changes locale for all app, not only for calling activity, but you might have to restart the app for the changes to apply.

Answer (score 4):

well you have to extends Application class and create a subclass from that

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

onCreate(){
//set you locale
}
```

and you can mention it in your menifest file like

```
<application name="MyApp">

.....
</application>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I thought this was the obvious solution as well, but it doesn't really seem to work.