# How to set my App to German Locale

Tags: android, locale

My question is much the same as this one, but unfortunately it was never answered.

[how to set application locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712765/how-to-set-application-locale)

I am actually trying to load the app onto the market place but it is showing that the default language is English when I upload it. I am guessing that there is a setting in the manifest file but can't find it.

All of the text in the app is in German but I just need the application to show this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose your default language in the parameters in the Market as follow:

1st step

[image: Step 1]

2nd step

[image: Step 2]

3rd step

[image: Step 3]

Last step

[image: Step 4]

My interface is in french but it is basically the same.

Comment: Yes a colleague figured this out in the end. I was sure that when I uploaded the app it was reading my manifest file and setting English as default. It took a while before I realised you can delete english as a language

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210127121431/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html

You can also use the default files to force german.

Instead of having:

strings-en.xml
strings-de.xml
strings-ch.xml
...

Use strings.xml only, and put german strings there. Any user will see german.

Comment: So the only way is to set the locale programmatically?

Comment: No. Use the default values. Like values/strings.xml and not strings-de.xml or strings-en.xml... If you just use ONE strings.xml this will always be read. That IS the standard language.

Answer (score 0):

If your resources are [localized](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) to German then anyone with a German-localized phone should see everything in German.

Comment: There are no options for other languages. It's just in German. I want to set it so you can download the app and read German, if you have an English localised phone you will still read German.