# new locale in android (urdu/pakistan)

Tags: android, locale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Locale programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically)

I am a beginner in android. making my first app, all i want to do is localize my app to urdu language/pakistan. what should i do. 
Where I can get the list of all android locale?

Answer (score 5):

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127121431/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html) may be helpful, code of Urdu - Pakistan is ur-PK, which may not be present for your use. List of all android locale can be found [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596004) or [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html). Also take a look at [localization tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html)

---

If you want to use **urdu** font for showing text in a view(say TextView) then:

---

### Code for setting custom font to TextView:

Assuming you have a urdu ttf font say(**URDU.ttf**) font in **fonts** folder under **assets** folder:

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/URDU.ttf");               
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: @Haris do you want to provide localization even though it is not available or just want to show urdu?

Comment: I want to localize it in urdu/pakistan, not merely writing urdu