# Android i18N based on dynamic input

Tags: android, localization

I want to localize my android app based on user defined language instead of device locale. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't you mean _L10n_ :p Also, your question is kind of vague. Are you asking how to localize a program in general?

Comment: You mean that they enter french within your app? In that case I'm back to my original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically

Comment: you can set your custom locale at application level. do you want some thing like Japanese lang in your app, english lang on Device. AFAIK what you can do is set you custom locale at the start of app and at the time of app close, restore default locale.