# translate my app

Tags: android, internationalization, translation

What I want to do is provide the user with a spinner which contains several languages, when a language is selected, the app will translate to that language.

I have different string files but I have no idea how to implement this. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Just google "Android i18n" (i18n = internationalization) and you'll get lots of resources, like [this one](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/01/17/translating-android-applications-i18n/)

Comment: chick this [page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) and this seems to be duplicate of [setting locale programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the res folder, respect this :

```
res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es / (here for spanish values)
           strings.xml
       values-fr /
           strings.xml (here for french values)
```

Android loads the appropriate resources according to the locale settings of the device at run time.

For more informations, see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put different `string.xml` files in different values folders each one named like this **values-XX** where XX is the language to be used.

for examlple values-en for english, values-fr for french, etc..