# android help system how to display html files

Tags: java, android, html

I would like to make help system for my app. My idea is to display full screen dialog (or almost full size) with html pages. Moreover I would like to work this help system fully offline and not to use any external web browser. Additionally help system should be ready for few languages support.

How should I do that? Is there any widget ready from shelf. How to put html pages as resources (language dependend)?

Any other suggestions how to prepare good help system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer is correct. Just to add on it, you can also convert the html content to XML and keep it in the `strings.xml` file. Then you can use the resource as you use the normal string.

```
WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.loadData( getString(R.string.ResourceName), "text/html", "utf-8" );
```

or

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL( null, getString(R.string.ResourceName), "text/html", "utf-8", null );
```

**EDIT**- [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/infivivek/resourse-centre/online-resources/html-to-xml-converter) is the link for HTML to XML conversion.

For multiple language support follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) link.

For each HTML file just convert it into XML. Then -

```
<string name="help">Your XML content</string>
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot! how to convert html to xml? do I understand well for each html file I will have one xml file in string folder? and how to make the help system language dependend (android opens automaticaly file for the appropriate language)?

Comment: Great man, you are very helpful. Now I know all what I needed, it's time to checking this in practice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: the file index.html should be inside assets folder

Comment: how to inform Android which file to select depending on the language version (automatically)?

Comment: i didn't get you...??what version are u talking about?

Comment: I want to have the same file in many versions, ex. one for English, one for French, one for... etc. I would expect that Android will select automatically the appropriate version depending on the current system settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically

check this out....the answer will help you to get the language and set it as well... in your case you will not have to use the code for setting the language......but instead display the other webpage...

Answer (score 1):

Use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), and store your html files on the assets folder
e.g.

```
  WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
  webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");
```