# Disable some configurations for the app (for example locales)

Tags: java, android

How can I make my app to ignore certains configurations, for example, the device's language (forcint the app to use default strings)

For better understanding thats the concret problem:

I have a Android Library project with some strings in the strings.xml file

That library have the strings in **english**, **german**, **french** and **spanish**.

I want use the library in an app but this app only supports **english** and **german** so I'd like to ignore the strings provided by the library project in **french** and **spanish** in order to avoid a partial traduction

Is that possible without magical workarrounds?

Thanks

Comment: You could manually override the `Locale` on startup if it's an unsupported one. Easy in regular Java, not sure about Android.

Comment: Delete the string resources that you do not want from your copy of the library. As a bonus, your APK will be a bit smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the system Locale using this code

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

You can check if it's French or Spanish then you can enforce your own locale either English or German

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

some of the code taken from [Set Locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your app to the Market, you can select which markets to ship to.