# Dynamic localisation

Tags: android, string, localization, android-location

I am stuck up in a problem since last few days. I am creating an application for a worldwide release for which the strings will come from server side means dynamic localisation and as we all know that we can not modify strings.xml during runtime. So is there a method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the locale programatically at some point in your application.

Possibly at the beginning e.g the onCreate() method of your Base Activity

A similar question has been asked before: [Set Locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically)

As noted from the "reporter's comment below:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to change language:

```
private void setLocale (String localeCode , Bundle b)
{
    locale = new Locale(localeCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    UserDetail.this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    onCreate(null);
}
```

And call the function:

```
setLocale("en-us",savedInstanceStat); // English
```

Comment: I have already mentioned it in the question tht it is impossible to change string.xml at runtime.