# how to make application language independent of os language

Tags: android

i'm working on application that supports multiple languages and i want to make my application language away of os language so scenario happened to me

i selected english language from my app settings and every thing is localized pretty good
next i put my app in background then switched os languages to french then tried to resume my application and i found french string resources appears and if i killed the application and opened it again it will show my setting original language as i selected so can anyone help ne

Comment: Looks like this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4986481/2711056

Comment: @MyDogTom already implemented that ,, just i want to disable change on my resources if os language is changed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Locale programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically)

Comment: @user101530 The main idea that you change your locale in `onResume` method. If system change locale you will change it again during `onResume`.

Comment: @MyDogTom i tried ,,, not working

Comment: @user101530 I suggest you to edit your question. Add the code of how and where you do the locale change.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following method to change the users locale:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

This should do the trick.
The locale for english for example is: 'en' or for german it is 'de'.

Comment: this is not the state that i'm talking about, i can change my localization from my app settings freely but if the i changed os language it affects my application too

Comment: Ah okay, sry I missunderstood your question.