# Change language in UI on the fly Android

Tags: android, localization, runtime

I created an application with localized strings in Spanish and English, located at `res/values` (Spanish is default) and `res/values-en`. The application display the language as the system, but how can I change the application language separatedly of the system?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should set Locale programatically 
as explained here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986481/1531683

Comment: With some changes, it works for me. I had to reduce the language list. And force application restart after language change.