# Xamarin cross platform localize images

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have an application in Xamarin crossplatfrom. I created a solution for localize strings and it is working perfect. I am setting:

```
StringResources.Culture = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
```

But I have a problem with image resoruces. I created folders in android app:

```
drawable, drawable-pl-rPL, drawable-pl-rPL-hdpi, drawable-pl-rPL-ldpi, drawable-pl-rPL-mdpi
```

But I have no idea how to set global culture for app. I was trying to put in MainActivity class:

```
var ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lastLanguage);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

Where lastLanguage is a code for lasdt selcted language (en or pl-PL). But it is not working, image is always taken from drawable folder, no from drawable-pl-rPL

Can you help me somehow?

Comment: You probably need to change the local on the android os level. Here is an example of how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/4986481/1341538

Comment: No it doesn't work. When I debug OnCreate method in MainActivity and check resources->Locale it is pl-PL but images are shown from main folder