# Android. How change default locale fo string.xml in values

Tags: android, locale

I have an application with only russian locale. If I am not mistaken, the `string.xml` in the `res/values` is the  english locale by default. But english and russian have different plurals. For example:

In russian:

- 1,21,31..x1 книга
- 2-4, 2(2-4), 3(2-4), .., x(2-4) книги
- in other cases - книг

In english:

- 1 book
- n books

Problems begin when the user changes system language from russian to other language.
How can I change default language for my application? Or maybe it is possible to force the application to use the russian plurals?

Comment: @vladimir Did you see this question : [set-locale-programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically), you can force to use any language. I can show you if you dont get any idea by looking question.

Comment: Yes, but it does not answer my question. I need that would be the default string.xml used russian plurals.

Comment: I don't want to set locale programmatically.

Comment: Please read my question carefully). I have all my strings in default folder.  string.xml in default values uses english plurals, not russian.
I have problem:
"1 книга", but always "n книг". Such in english: "1 book", "n books". But this is wrong for russian.

Comment: hmm now i understand , sorry.

Comment: Hi @ВладимирШироков! Have you found an answer for this?

Comment: Hi @gmazzo! Unfortunately not. You probably need to add the translation to English. Or handle problem words manually. Or leave it as it is.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the answer:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolslocale

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:locale="es">
```

From the doc:

> This tells the tools **what the default language/locale is** for the resources in the given  element (because the tools **otherwise assume English**) in order to avoid warnings from the spell checker. The value must be a valid locale qualifier.

Comment: This does not change the way plurals work in the app, only changes behavior for lint. With English set on device it will still show wrong plurals.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different String.xml files

like this

```
values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

Check google official document https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html 
& https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: That does not answer my question. values - folder by default. I have only one language. But default uses english plurals.

Answer (score 0):

create new value folder values-ru and place string.xml in that.

in java change your app language programatically with this code. for change to rushion call method with ru parameter like this changeLanguage("ru").

```
public void changeLanguage(String languageToLoad) {
        //for language change
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```