# How to pre empt what getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry() will return

Tags: android

Is there a way to know what 
   getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry()

Will return for each country?  I see for my country it returns "South Africa" but what will it return for America or England etc?

Comment: you can use the android emulator and change the locale there. There is an app on it called custom locale and that should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks i tried that but it doesnt seem to work on the emulator when i try

                String locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();


It always returns null

Comment: even better actually you can set the locale just to test. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically hope this will help