# How to set Locale for Spanish Latin America?

Tags: android, string, locale

How to set Locale for Spanish Latin America?
I have stored all my strings in values-b+es+r419 folder for Spanish Latin America. But unable to set this language in locale.App is showing only default language, not changing the language of app.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es","419"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale); 
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {         
    config.setLocale(locale); 
} else{ 
    config.locale=locale; 
} 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { 
    context.createConfigurationContext(config); 
} else { 
    context.getResources()
           .updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
}
```

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269965/886001) to change locale programmatically.. that way you'll be getting resources from the desired locale

Comment: Thanks for reply,But i want to know code for Spanish Latin America while setting locale by coding           LanguageHelper.setAppLocale("fa", this); // therefore what is the reeplacement of "fa" for values-b+es+r419

Comment: I see.. as provided in the previous link to set locale you use `configuration.setLocale(new Locale("es", "419"))`.. let me know if this helps

Comment: But my app language still not changing.It shows only default language.

Comment: in this case post the code you've tried so far.. so we can have more understanding about what's not working

Comment: Locale locale = locale = new Locale("es","419");

   Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();



if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
    config.setLocale(locale);
} else{
    config.locale=locale;
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
    context.createConfigurationContext(config);
} else {
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}   // here is my code

Comment: first don't create `new Configuration()` use `getResources().getConfiguration()` instead.. then you need to restart activity to fetch correct resources using `activity.recreate()`

Comment: and change `Locale locale = locale = new Locale("es","419"); ` to this `Locale locale = new Locale("es","419"); `

Comment: I make these changes in  my app but  now it showing strings of spanish(es) language, not showing strings of Spanish latin America(es_419)

Comment: My app still not recognizing b+es+r419

Comment: according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) your qualifier for values should be `b+es+419`.. you can find language tags [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) as well