# Android App Bundle with in-app locale change

Tags: android, locale, android-app-bundle

I've a problem with AAB when I need to change the app locale from within the app itself(i.e. have the language change setting inside the app), the issue is that the AAB gives me only my device languages resources, for example:

my device has English and French languages installed in it, so AAb gives me only the resources for English and French,

but from within the app itself there is a choice to switch the language between English, French, and Indonesian,

in that case, when changing the language to English or French everything is working perfectly, but when changing it to Indonesian, the app simply enters a crash loop as it keep looking for Indonesian language but it can't find.

The problem here is that even if I restarted the app, it enters the crash loop again as the app is still looking for the missing language resources, and here the only solution is to clear cash or reinstall which are the solutions that the normal user won't go through.

---

Just to mention it, this is how I change the locale through the app:

```
    // get resources
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    // create the corresponding locale
    Locale locale = new Locale(language); // for example "en"
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        conf.setLocale(locale);
        conf.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    } else {
        conf.locale = locale;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        context.getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(conf);
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
```

---

P.S. The app is working perfectly when build it as APK.

Comment: Did you find any better solutions yet?

Comment: @AnkitDubariya the best one so far is the one provided by Pierre

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71793460/12272687

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Edit:**

The **PlayCore API** now supports downloading the strings for another language on-demand:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand#lang_resources

**Alternative solution (discouraged):**

You can disable the splitting by language by adding the following configuration in your build.gradle

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

This latter solution will increase the size of the app.

Comment: Did you find any better solutions yet?

Comment: Another solution is now available. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hi @Pierre maybe you can help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630355/how-to-fix-program-type-already-present-error-when-dynamic-feature-is-using-an

Comment: Is the increasement of the size really that big? I have a lot of users with almost no-reliable internet connection and I am thinking of the trade-off between more size and internet required to change language. (Having 4 languages only)

Comment: It will be different for each app. 4 languages is not much so probably not a massive difference in your case, but you can build both aab then use bundletool to generate the APKs locally and the get-size command to see the difference in APK size.

Comment: It amazes me how Google breaks something which was working flawlessly for 10 years just so we can spare a few megabytes of apk size in the age of 4k movies, mobile mmorpgs and 5g internet.

Comment: If by breaking you mean offering a solution through a library, then indeed. If by the age of 5g internet, you mean US and Western Europe in metropolitan areas, agreed as well. And if you mean than in 10 years, size of APKs has grown exponentially, then spot on again! We're in agreement it seems :)

Answer (score 8):

Details of downloading the language on demand can be found here

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/the-latest-android-app-bundle-updates.html

In your app’s `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is downloaded from the Google’s Maven repository.
    // So, make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'

    // For Kotlin users also add the Kotlin extensions library for Play Core:
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
    ...
}
```

Get a list of installed languages

```
val splitInstallManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(context)
val langs: Set<String> = splitInstallManager.installedLanguages
```

Requesting additional languages

```
val installRequestBuilder = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
installRequestBuilder.addLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("pl"))
splitInstallManager.startInstall(installRequestBuilder.build())
```

Check above link for full details

Comment: could you please explain what exactly is meant with additional languages? My app has three languages and a language is selected according the device's language. I use in my app's gradle this one  `defaultConfig { resourceConfigurations += arrayOf("en", "de", "ru") }`, in Manifest `android:installLocation="auto"` and `android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"`, which is provided from the xm file that includes `<locale-config>
    <locale android:name="en"/>
    <locale android:name="de"/>
    <locale android:name="ru"/>
</locale-config>`

But still get a warning of App Bundle handling...

Answer (score 7):

After many hours I was finally able to use the on-demand language with the new PlayCore API.

**Step 1.)** As the user changes the language, you need to first check whether the language is already available, if not then download the language

```
private void changeLocale(final String languageSelected){
  SplitInstallManager splitInstallManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(PlayAgainstComputer.this);
    final Set<String> installedLangs = splitInstallManager.getInstalledLanguages();
    if(installedLangs.contains(languageSelected)){ // checking if lang already available
        Toast.makeText(PlayAgainstComputer.this,"Done! The language settings will take effect, once you restart the app!").show();
    }
    else{
        SplitInstallRequest request =
                SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag(languageSelected))
                        .build();
        splitInstallManager.startInstall(request);
        splitInstallManager.registerListener(new SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateUpdate(@NonNull SplitInstallSessionState splitInstallSessionState) {
            if(splitInstallSessionState.status() == SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED){
                Toast.makeText(PlayAgainstComputer.this,"Download complete! The language settings will take effect, once you restart the app!").show();
            }
        }
    });
 }}
```

**Step2.)** The downloaded languages must be installed when the user starts the app. which is done in the `attchBaseContext()` method

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    SplitCompat.install(this); // It will install all the downloaded langauges into the app
  }
```

**Step 3.)** You need to tell the Activity to use the chosen language. Following code should be placed before `setContentView(R.layout.layout);` of that activity

```
  String selectedLanguage = getFromPrefernceOrWhereEverYouSavedIt(); // should be 2 letters. like "de", "es"
  Locale locale = new Locale(selectedLanguage); 
  Locale.setDefault(locale);
  Resources resources = getResources();
  Configuration config = new Configuration(resources.getConfiguration());
  config.locale = locale;
  resources.updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

**Done!**

**Please Note**

When a user (who chose a non-default/downloaded language) updates the app, that language needs to be downloaded again into the app, so make sure you handle that in your code.

when I used `activity.recreate();` after the download finished (to automatically refresh the app for new language) I faced some problems, that is why I used `Toast` to ask the user to manually restart the app. but you can try other methods

I also noticed some other inconsistencies (even sometimes faced memory leak because of   `SplitCompat.install(this);`) with this method, so make sure you test and optimize it according to your code.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with app bundles: Google Play only downloads resources when the device's selected languages change.

You'll have to use APKs if you want to have an in app language picker.

Comment: What will happend if a device is offline and user change the locale? Will it crash? Will the app provide default interface (english). And downloading proper locale will be scheduled to next connection?

Comment: It just won't switch until the device is back online. Yes, the download is automatically scheduled for you - there's nothing your app needs to do.

Comment: @TouhidulIslam - it wasn't possible in October 2018, when this answer was written.

Comment: Is this still not supported with app bundles ?  Do we still have to use APKs for having app language picker ?

Comment: Google Play is enforcing Bundle by 2021, does that means we can't have in-app language picker anymore?

Comment: This is not/no longer correct. See other answers here, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#android12-impl or https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/11/per-app-language-preferences-part-1.html on how to disable bundle split by language OR download extra language resources when needed.