# Multilingual strings are not displaying in app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

- I had this setting in gradle
- I had uploaded `.aab` playstore.
- The app is multilingual namely `English` and `Bahasa`

---

```
android {
    // When building Android App Bundles, the splits block is ignored.
    splits {...}

    // Instead, use the bundle block to control which types of configuration APKs
    // you want your app bundle to support.
    bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = true
        }
        density {
            // This property is set to true by default.
            enableSplit = true
        }
        abi {
            // This property is set to true by default.
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**: Once I downloaded app from play-store i can just see `English` strings in app and `Bahasa` language is not coming when I switch the language

**Question** : Does specifying `language-split = true` causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jael ... Has a good answer which he shared which I was not aware of so [+1] for the help

But I could resolve this by

```
language { enableSplit = false }
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything you're doing is okay, it seems that when your device doesn't contains specified language you selected from app *(I.e. language settings from App)*, **Play core library** fails to fetch that resources for you because your device doesn't support that Locale.

So, the solution is to manually request for it to download that resources for you.

You can do that by making request to `SplitsInstallManager`.

Create your new `SplitsInstallRequest` and provide it to `SplitsInstallManager` so that it would provide that resources for you.

Check out code snippet below:

```
// Creates a request to download and install additional language resources.
val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
    // Uses the addLanguage() method to include French language resources in the request.
    // Note that country codes are ignored. That is, if your app
    // includes resources for “fr-FR” and “fr-CA”, resources for both
    // country codes are downloaded when requesting resources for "fr".
    .addLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("your language code here"))
    .build()

// Submits the request to install the additional language resources.
splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
```

**[Refer here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#lang_resources)** about more details.

Comment: How do you change your language? Is it from settings page of your app? If yes, when language changes, request it manually from there.

Comment: I am using `LocaleHelper.setLocale(context, language);` from within the app to change the language

Comment: Yes, you can then request for your locale from SplitsIntallRequest.

Comment: Yes, because aab works with splits apks. So there are multiple apk files based on configurations and dynamic modules.

Comment: Cant I just use `language { enableSplit = false }`

Comment: No, this won't take effect when you've not that language added in default languages. Refer this question also : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52731670/10271334