# Why does the language file (locale) not work on a real device?

Tags: android, kotlin, locale, multilingual

I made several language files strings.xml(de, en and others). I'm trying to change the locale to display values from the correct language file with help the following code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setAppLocale("hy")
        val actionBar: androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar? = supportActionBar
        actionBar?.hide()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        .....
    }
    
    fun Context.setAppLocale(language: String): Context {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val config = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
        return createConfigurationContext(config)
    }
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(ContextWrapper(newBase.setAppLocale("hy")))
    }
    
}
```

implementation

```
implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
```

on emulator, this code works and the text from the desired language file (string-hy) is displayed on the device screen. But on a real device, the required language file is not pulled up, although the check shows that the locale has been changed. I can't figure out what the problem is. And such an problem with different codes for changing languages. Please tell me what could be the problem?

UPD: maybe someone can share working code for changing language to java or kotlin ?

UPD2: **code is not working in app in google play only with android app bundle.**

---

**Solution:**
similar questions with multiple solutions: **[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405466/android-app-bundle-not-supporting-dynamic-language-change)** and **[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731670/android-app-bundle-with-in-app-locale-change)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working code:

```
    fun setAppLocale(language: String) {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val config = resources.configuration
        config.locale = locale
        activity.resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
```

Edit: Google splits your app in other languages automatically. But in your case, you wrote your locale strings by yourself. So disable that in your `build.gradle(:app)` :

```
android {
    ...
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code work at a real application in Google Play?

Comment: Yes, i am using it on my app which is live on Google Play. Be sure it's working on your local, then safely update it to store.

Comment: this is not my first attempt. I am faced with the fact that language switching does not work exactly in the application downloaded via google play. Maybe i should change something in the developer console?

Comment: I checked my app and updated my answer.

Comment: I already found the same answer and was about to close the question, but I saw your comment. Thank you!