# Xamarin.Android - Can't change app locale after Google Play release

Tags: android, xamarin.android, localization, google-play, locale

I have developed an Android application with a feature that allows you to change the entire App locale language. It works perfectly in Debug mode. Unfortunately after the release in the Play Store this feature no longer works.

I have already seen these questions, where they say that it would be enough to edit the build.gradle file.

[Android App Locale Not Working on Play Store Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298424/android-app-locale-not-working-on-play-store-release)

[Android App Bundle with in-app locale change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731670/android-app-bundle-with-in-app-locale-change/52733674#52733674)

```
android {
    //...
    //... removed for brevity
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I developed it in Xamarin.Android and not in Android Studio and so I have no idea how I could modify that file and achieve the same result. I also do not want to support download on demand.

Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to found a solution and fix my issue.

First, I have added this file `BundleConfig.json` to my project.

```
{
  "optimizations": {
    "splitsConfig": {
      "splitDimension": [{
        "value": "LANGUAGE",
        "negate": true
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Second, I edited my project's csproj file, adding a AndroidBundleConfigurationFile item under the release PropertyGroup.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <AndroidBundleConfigurationFile>BundleConfig.json</AndroidBundleConfigurationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then, I saved the solution, recreated my aab bundle, and locales were being changed correctly on release mode.

**Sources:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/10/10.3#support-for-android-app-bundle-configuration-files

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundleconfig

Comment: This was a life saver, thankyou