# Get ringtone - english name

Tags: java, android, android-context, ringtonemanager

I want to get the ringtones of a phone, but see only the english (non-localized version).

My theory, was using a ContextWrapper, and set that context locale to `en_US` and pass that new locale to `RingtoneManager.getRingtone()` (code based from [Set Locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programmatically) ):

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
Context cc = setContextLocale(cw, "en_US"); // This method was copied from the StackOverflow question above ^^
Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(cc,  Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
String sss = defaultRingtone.getTitle(cc);
```

So, yes, this does not work as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't ringtone names are localizes when I change system language. I'm using emulator with Android 9.0 for testing. Do you see those ringtones localized? If yes which device and which Android version do you have

Comment: On Pixel2 (emulator) ringtones are not translated (funny, settings crashes), however on Pixel3 (real HW) I can see the ringtones translated. I am unable to find in the settings code where those translations come from. Again, funny.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you find what you are looking for with following code snippet:

```
        data class Ringtone(
            val _id: String,
            val title: String
        )
        val cursor = RingtoneManager(this).cursor
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val list = ArrayList<Ringtone>()
        do {
            list.add(Ringtone(
                cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1)
            ))
        } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        Log.i(TAG, "ringtones list=$list")
```