# Can not change app language programmatically: got expected result at first but language is not changing after I changed build variant

Tags: android, locale

I need to set my app's locale to Bangla. And to do that, I coded in the following way:

```
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
//        Log.d(TAG, "attachBaseContext: BASE CONTEXT CALLED");
        Locale mLocale = new Locale("bn");
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setLocale(mLocale);

        final Context newContext = newBase.createConfigurationContext(config);
        super.attachBaseContext(newContext);
    }
```

I kept on running my app in **debug build variant** and it worked fine.

However, after switching to **release build variant**, it didn't work and all the texts of my app was in English only.

I searched through stackoverflow and found [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4985805/8192914). I tried out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269965/8192914) and coded in the following way:

```
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(newBase));
    }

    private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context) {
//        String language = SharedPrefUtils.getSavedLanguage(); // Helper method to get saved language from SharedPreferences
        Locale locale = new Locale("bn");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale);
        }

        return updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context, locale);
    }

    //    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)
    private Context updateResourcesLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    //    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Context updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            // update overrideConfiguration with your locale
            setLocale(overrideConfiguration); // you will need to implement this
        }
        super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
    }

    private void setLocale(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("bn");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            overrideConfiguration.setLocale(locale);
        } else {
            overrideConfiguration.locale = locale;
        }
    }
```

But it didn't produce the expected result. I created another simple hello-world project to test this code out. And when I ran it for the first time (in debug variant), the text appeared in Bangla. And I didn't even need to override `applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration)` like I did in the code above. However, after ran my app in release mode, the same problem occurred. And it persisted even after switching to debug mode.

I tried changing `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` to `appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02` and `appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01` but still no luck.

I used android Pie device and android Q emulator to run my app.

Is changing build variant solely responsible for this? Or is there any bug in my code? I would appreciate if someone shares a better approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Try to keep AppCompat classes by adding the below line in "proguard-rules.pro" file:
-keep class androidx.appcompat.app.** { *; }

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way it's use library like - [Localization](https://github.com/akexorcist/Localization)

But if you want to have your own solution - simply check the library source code and I believe that you will find all answers there.