# Xamarin.Android : change app language programmatically?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, localization

I have 2 `strings.xml` files in their `values-en` and `values-fr` folders. When I change language from Android settings, app is correctly localized.

However, is there a way to change app language programmatically ? The following code (as suggested by recents stackoverflow posts on that subject) does not have any effect on localization :

```
var locale = new Java.Util.Locale("fr");
Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;
var context = Application.Context;
context.Resources.Configuration.Locale = locale;
    
BaseContext.ApplicationContext.CreateConfigurationContext(context.Resources.Configuration);
BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
```

Indeed, a string after this code with `GetString(Resource.String.stringName)` will remain in english.

**target version :**  Android 8.1 (API 27 - Oreo)

AppCompat Activity using Android.Support.V7.App (only to use a FAB in Android.Support.Design.Widget)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createConfigurationContext(configuration)` is not enough, We need  need to get the context that this method returns and then to set this context in the attachBaseContext method.

```
    protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
    {
        base.AttachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(@base));
    }

    private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context)
    {
        var locale = new Java.Util.Locale("sp");
        Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
        {
            Configuration configuration = context.Resources.Configuration;
            configuration.SetLocale(locale);

            return context.CreateConfigurationContext(configuration);
        }
        else
        {
            Resources resources = context.Resources;
            Configuration configuration = resources.Configuration;
     #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            configuration.Locale = locale;
            resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, resources.DisplayMetrics);
     #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

            return context;
        }         
    }
```

#### Get string in OnCreate method

```
   string title = GetString(Resource.String.TxtWelcome);
```

---

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44571077/8187800

Comment: I used this code in the `OnCreate` method, the only modification being `var locale = new Java.Util.Locale("en");`but the language remains in french.
Moreother, it seems that `Resources.UpdateConfiguration` is deprecated. Hence I tried to use `CreateConfigurationContext` that should replace it.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot ! I was unable to find proper documentation on that subject.