# Change default language strings.xml on Android

Tags: java, android

I've test the app "Daylio" and at the startup i've see a little dropdownlist with the possibility of choose the language of your choice.
But, how can it work ?
In my app I have a strings.xml for any language, and it's the problem. For example, if i'm English and if i have a spanish phone, app & strings xml will detect i'm spanish, and that's my question : How can we change the default strings.xml used on the phone user ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you looked at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programmatically
?

Comment: No i haven't find this ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Yes thank you, how can I validate this page ?