# Radio group text strangely misaligned in RTL language

Tags: android, android-layout

Radio group behaves strangely on my phone and the text is totally misaligned as shown in the image below, but the strange thing is that it's aligned correctly in the XML layout visualizer in android studio

**Misaligned Image on my phone**

[image: MisAligned image]

The perfectly fine image on XML layout visualizer in android studio
[image]

**The XML code of the layout**

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mlns="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_28dp_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_screen"
    mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ------
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/HintTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_36dp_dp"
        android:text="@string/language"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tg_group_language"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/et_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_phone" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/tg_group_language"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30dp_dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_save_changes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/et_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/et_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_english"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/english" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_arabic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/عربي" />

    </RadioGroup>

   -----


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**NB**:

- I didn't apply any styling programmatically
- It seems it works fine when the language of the phone is RTL
  but when trying to force the language of the app to RTL while the phone is LTR (English) using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269965/10138208), it shows this misalignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution worked for me was adding this line in each radio button

```xml
 android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code your AndroidManifest xml file

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

...

Comment: I had already applied supportsRTL in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="right"` in each `RadioButton` as follow..

```
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/radios"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:inputType="text"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawablePadding="30dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:text="first"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="20dip" 
    android:gravity="right"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawablePadding="30dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:text="second"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="20dp"
     android:gravity="right"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/third"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Maroon"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawablePadding="30dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:text="third"
    android:textColor="@color/Vanilla"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

Comment: This solved it in the RTL  screen but produced same issue when tried LTR language

Answer (score 0):

```
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/et_name"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/et_name"
```

You got misalignment because of these two lines.if you want radio group at center use parent instead of et_name.

```
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Comment: I tried but this didn't solve it, actually, I don't know why these two lines will produce a problem everything mentioned in the whole XML is either end or start there are no left or right so everything should be positioned right