# How to apply Locale to Plural resource?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using plurals in resources just like docs saying:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals

My app using only one language, so i want to use my language's rules no matter which language is set on device. How can i use Locale in my plurals?

```
<plurals name="amount_of_hours">
        <item quantity="zero">%d zero</item>
        <item quantity="one">%d one</item>
        <item quantity="two">%d two</item>
        <item quantity="few">%d few</item>
        <item quantity="many">%d many</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d other</item>
    </plurals>

// set Locale to this plural 
context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.amount_of_hours, hours, hours)
```

Comment: Why do you need to set a locale? If there is only one language in your app? do you observe some issues with plurals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Configuration` with a different locale as described in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269965/2921519 and call `getQuantityString` on it:

```
val configuration = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
configuration.setLocale(locale)

// For N or above only. See linked answer for backwards compatibility.
val localeContext = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
localeContext.resources.getQuantityString(...)
```