# How to read android project strings.xml in android project at runtime line by line

Tags: android

Basically at run time I want to read the entire file line by like. I tried the below and always getting a null. If there is a correct way to do what I need thanks!

InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/values/strings.xml");

I tried different combinations of the path like just strings.xml and strings and /res/values/strings.xml and it did not work either.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Read xml value or full string file including xml tags ?

Comment: You can read all the values. Instead of reading the entire file which is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Ricky - I want to create a copy of the file at run time. Shivanshu I want to read the entire string including tags. Haris, this is for international reasons so I need the names and values from the file. I tried reflection and could only get names and not that plus the values.

Comment: I could do a brute force solution and copy the contents of strings.xml to another file and store it where I can get to it easier. But, I was trying to be conservative.

Comment: That `strings.xml` file and name don't really exist in any form at runtime. Its contents are basically lumped together with all the other stuff inside `<resources>` tags in all the other `res/values/` files then processed by type: `string`s, `color`s, `style`s, etc. I'm not sure exactly what you need for the international, but Android inherently supports resource localization out of the box: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages. If you really do need the file at runtime, you'll have to pack an unprocessed copy, which you can put in `res/raw/` or `assets/`.

Comment: Thanks Mike I was wondering if that is the case. You confirmed what I suspected also of assets/ and I did not know about res/raw. Many Thanks!

Comment: So I am wondering if I can force the loading from that location. So if I have french strings can the "french" locale be read from that directory there or any folder I have created? I read somewhere about using the assets folder.

Comment: Yeah, but it won't involve assets; not sure what that method might've been. At runtime, resources are loaded through instances of the `Context` class – e.g., `Activity` and `Service` classes – and a `Context`'s `Resources` holds a `Locale` object that determines which directory to pull from (though those directories don't really exist at runtime; you know what I mean). I'm not terribly familiar with changing the `Locale` there, but I know it varies a bit between Android versions, and can be finicky. I'd start with these: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2900023, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4985805.

Comment: I am trying the second link and working on getting the sample code running. I posted a question to try to get what I hope is the last issue with the example resolved.